# Permission tmp problem: Change of tmp directory

Tags: files

I recently installed one new Drupal (7.32) on a server that doesn't belong to me. Since then, I have a permission problem, I can't edit CHMOD rights and when I try to add new content (with image(s)), I can't. Here's the mistake returned by Drupal:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(/home/tmp/php/phpBKRRLYL) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/tmp/sessions/:/home/XXX/public_html/:/home/XXX/shared) in drupal_move_uploaded_file() (line 1639 of /home/XXX/www/public_html/YYY/drupal-7.32/includes/file.inc).

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(/home/tmp/php/phpBKRRLYL) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/tmp/sessions/:/home/XXX/public_html/:/home/XXX/shared) in drupal_move_uploaded_file() (line 1639 of /home/XXX/www/public_html/YYY/drupal-7.32/includes/file.inc).

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/home/tmp/php/phpBKRRLYL): failed to open stream:
Operation not permitted in drupal_move_uploaded_file() (line 1639 of /home/XXX/www/public_html/YYY/drupal-7.32/includes/file.inc).

Warning: move_uploaded_file():
Unable to move '/home/tmp/php/phpBKRRLYL' to '/home/XXX/www/public_html/YYY/drupal-7.32/sites/default/files/anime.jpg' in drupal_move_uploaded_file() (line 1639 of /home/XXX/www/public_html/YYY/drupal-7.32/includes/file.inc).
```

As we can see, Drupal apparently uses the server's tmp directory (in which I have no rights) and I would like it to use another tmp directory in "/home/XXX/www/public_html/YYY/drupal-7.32/" so that I can add/edit content properly.
How could I do this? By editing the "/includes/file.inc" file (if so, which line(s) shall I modify to do this?)? Something else?

NB: The system administrator is unavailable for an extended period so he can't change my rights for now. That's why it's important that I could change this tmp directory.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the relevant setting in Configuration > Media > File system > Temporary directory (`/admin/config/media/file-system`).

You can choose any directory in your document root skipping the forward slash. I would recommend you to specify `tmp`. Take care of the permissions.

Comment: I tried by changing it to "/home/XXX/www/public_html/YYY/drupal-7.32/tmp" or "/sites/default/files/tmp", even "tmp", same problem. :/

Comment: Manually create a folder called tmp in your drupal root, then save the setting as tmp.

Comment: It's not working either. Just to be sure I'm not mistaken, I created a "temp" directory here : "/www/public_html/captainetwork/drupal-7.32/temp" with 775 rights and change the temp directory in file-system to "temp", is that the right way to do?

Comment: If your base url is public_html then possibly (not sure) you need to specify `captainetwork/drupal-7.32/temp` or change your $base_url in `settings.php`.

Comment: The temp directory has to be writable by the web server. So if you use 775 then either the owner or group of the folder must be that of the webserver.

Comment: If you give it 777 permissions and it still doesn't work then you at least know that it isn't a permissions problem, in which case it is probably for some reason looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Indeed, I gave it 777 permissions and I still have the error, but the same error (with /home/tmp/php/phpBKRRLYL, not "temp").

Comment: Another track perhaps? If the change of the temp directory on file-system is not changing the tmp directory where Drupal stores its data, what else can I do? Is there a file I can edit (if so, which line(s)?), one extra module to modify it? Else? Thanks for your previous helps!


**Edit :** I just see that there is no .htaccess file. And when I try to upload it, it's automatically deleted after the upload. Is there a possible link between this and my problem?

Comment: @Kiritsu, this is a Q+A website, sorry but we cannot troubleshoot for you. The tmp dir is specified as stated above and in rooby's comments, and this pretty much answers your question. There may possibly be something not properly setup with your web server or your Drupal installation.

Comment: I understand ;) You all helpt me a lot already, I found the issue when I found that the .htaccess was automatically deleted. I will try to correct that problem now!

Thanks again!